# A WebService annotation is not present on class: java.net.URL

Tags: web-services, client, wsimport, java-5

i generated a webservice client in netbeans(jdk1.6) and target client to jdk1.5.03. Then i moved all libs to jdk1.5 classpath and when i run WS Client, i got: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerErrorCaused by: A WebService annotation is not present on class: java.net.URL i generated it with wsimport.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessng that you probably either need to run JRE 1.6 on your target client, or set the target version to JDK 1.5 in NetBeans.

However, take a look at this link for other potential issues:

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?71220-Consuming-web-services

Comment: yes, but i dont use any swing api. WS call is the same as in jdk1.6. even classes are the same. still got that err. its possible that i have incompatible libs imported?